# If not or if not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

All theses tables `ERTBatches`, `ERTBatchChecks`, `ERTClaims` have an identifier.
Lets say the identifier is 1010.
This identifier must exist in all three tables.

I'm trying to find out if any identifer is not in all three tables.

These are the names of the Identifiers :

```
ERTBatches."BatchIdentifier"
ERTClaims."ERTBatchNumber"
ERTBatchChecks."BatchIdentifier"
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id
from ((select b.BatchIdentifier as id, 1 as which from ERTBatches b) union all
      (select bc.BatchIdentifier as id, 2 as which from ERTBatchChecks bc) union all
      (select c.ERTBatchNumber as id, 3 as which from ERTClaims c)
     ) t
group by id
having count(distinct which) < 3;
```

Comment: The ID is a random number in all three tables.

Comment: @JohnMolina . . . I don't understand the point of your comment.  This code should work on ids of almost any time, whether randomly assigned values or intentionally assigned values.

Comment: A small issue to correct is that you probably need to alias the 3 identifier cols as `id` in your select, given that the identfiers are named `ERTBatches.BatchIdentifier`,  `ERTBatchChecks.BatchIdentifier` & `ERTClaims.ERTBatchNumber`

Comment: Almost there! ;) the code also needs `as id` in each of the inner selects, e.g. `select b.BatchIdentifier as id,..`